# FLTK Fl_Tabs::remove()

Tags: c++

Возникла такая проблема:  Fl_Tabs::remove() принимает индекс страницы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне узнать индекс активной страницы?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Есть метод `Fl_Tabs::value`, который возвращает указатель на активный виджет, затем его надо передать в `Fl_Tabs::remove` (там три перегрузки).

Comment: @user7860670 , спасибо! Тоже наткнулся на него в последний момент))

Comment: @user7860670 , мне больше интересна эта задачка, что скажешь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1393489/315312